# How to import PyQt4 onto pycharm

Tags: pyqt, pycharm, pyqt4

I'm trying to import PyQt4 onto pycharm on Ubuntu
I successfully installed PyQt4 by using `sudo apt-get install python-qt4`, and I can import PyQt4 on terminal:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4
>>> quit()
```

But i just can't import PyQt4 onto Pycharm. I tried to add it onto the interpreter Paths, but when I run the code, it still shows `no module named PyQt4`
[image]

Comment: You have to select "/usr/lib/python2.7" as an interpreter, not just a folder. Press the button that has a screw icon and select the system python

Comment: @eyllanesc why can't I use the virtualenv python environemnt?

Comment: 1) You have used apt-get to install PyQt4 and consequently it was installed in the system python, so the only python that can use it is that python. 2) On the other hand I recommend using PyQt5 since PyQt4 has been deprecated for years, and if you choose PyQt5 then install it in the virtualenv with pycharm tools.

Comment: @eyllanesc the code was written by PyQt4. I saw it on PyQt website saying that transferring code from PyQt4 to PyQt5 is not easy, so I'm trying to install PyQt4 environment to make it run...

Comment: If you are going to support an answer with what others indicate it is good that you indicate the source, on the other hand of my experience the most important change was only that some classes (mainly widgets) were transferred to other modules, so if you are using pycharm la PyQt5 translation should be simple: 1) delete all PyQt4 imports and press "Ctrl + Alt + T" when the cursor is over a code that generates problems for pycharm to import

Comment: @eyllanesc what about the signal and slot stuff? It seems that PyQt5 no longer support it and change a new style writing it

Comment: If you understand how are the syntax of the connections in PyQt4 and PyQt5 then the translation is very simple, and in SO there are many examples that show the equivalences that would help you understand them.

Answer (score 0):

by this command `sudo apt-get install python-qt4` you download for python2 but actuly pycharm uses python3 so you should run this command : `sudo apt install python3-pyqt4`